# What does everything being vanity mean in Ecclesiastes 1?

Tags: ecclesiastes

> Vanity of vanities, saith the Preacher, vanity of vanities; all is
>   vanity. — Ecclesiasites 1:2, [KJV 2000](http://www.bartleby.com/108/21/1.html)

What is its literal meaning, in context?

Comment: Probable duplicate: [What translation best translates the word “vanity” (in the KJV) in Ecclesiastes?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1/3555)